# mysql get selection data to store in array but i only get 1 as return

Tags: php, mysql

```
    public function select($sql){
    $results = $this->connection_database->prepare($sql);

    $results->execute();

    if($results->rowCount() >0){};

    return $results;
  }

  public function prepare_product(){
    if(!empty($this->directoryfile)){
      $table = $this->directoryfile;
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";
      $results = $this->select($sql);

      //Fetch our results into an associative array
      $results = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      //The registration date of the stored matching user
      $productname = $results['DATA_PATH'];


      echo json_encode($productname);
    }
  }
```

lets said mysql database have `"ID"` and `"DATA_PATH"`, my intention is to get all the `"DATA_PATH"` data store in array , but i only get 1 `"DATA_PATH"` as return , what did i miss ?

can anyone give me some help ?

the data do return but i only get one , there is 5 item in my database.

Comment: YOU HAVE TO apply loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to:-

1.Create an array variable

2.Apply a loop

3.Assign all data to that array variable

4.At last apply `json_encode()` to that array variable

like below:-

```
$results = $this->select($sql);
$productname = array(); // create an array

while($row = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ // apply loop

      //The registration date of the stored matching user
      $productname[] = $row['DATA_PATH']; // assign value to that array
}
echo json_encode($productname); // json encode the array variable
```

Comment: Thanks :):). glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch ALL data not one. use `fetchAll`

```
public function prepare_product(){
    if(!empty($this->directoryfile)){
      $table = $this->directoryfile;
      $sql = "SELECT DATA_PATH FROM $table ";
      $results = $this->select($sql);


      //The registration date of the stored matching user
      $productname = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);


      echo json_encode($productname);
    }
  }
```